# What's the source for the Point Buy alternative ability score rules?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The player's handbook describes the process for determining ability scores via 4d6 drop the lowest (or, actually now that I think about it, it might just be 3d6 and the 4d6 drop might be *another* variant rule). But I have very rarely actually used that, and instead used the 'point buy' system, starting from 8 and 'buying' points up to a maximum of 18.

I can't find a source for that in the PHB, the DMG or the SRD. Where did it come from? A 3.0 book? A 2e book?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Point buy is described in the *DMG*

In *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on page 19 on Ability Scores Generation describes Standard Point Buy.

In *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on page 169 on Ability Scores describes Standard Point Buy.

The *SRD* deliberately omits the process of creating (and advancing) a character so that folks must buy *Player's Handbooks* (and maybe *Dungeon Master's Guides* and *Monster Manuals*) to play [d20 System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D20_System) games.

Comment: Beat me to it :(, was looking up the page number.

Comment: @Snappie Been there, man. My books happened to be open. `:-)`

Comment: Ok, thank you my friend. I must've just missed it. Or not search properly, it's not in the index under point buy ... or maybe it is. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @McCloud it's under "ability score generation" in the index :)

Answer (score 6):

Point buy first appeared in an official D&D rulebook in AD&D 2nd edition's “2.5e” books, the *Player's Option* line of supplements. These books tested out all kinds of new ideas, many of which were never revisited, but some of which eventually made it into later D&D editions — grid-based combat and point-buy ability scores being two prominent ones.

There were actually two point-buy methods introduced in *Player's Option: Skills & Powers* on pages 7–8, as **Method VII** and **Method X**. The fact that there are two is odd — the difference between the methods is only a minor note about how to handle Exceptional Strength — but underlines how much these books were experiments in throwing optional rules variations at the player base to see what stuck.

Point buy is one of the ideas that stuck. It would later appear in the 3rd edition DMG, and then the v3.5 PHB.